# Transition from one view to another in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a fairly basic setup but the transition doesn't seem to work.  Desired outcome is to fade Loading out and fade Content in.  Once the 2 seconds is up and isLoading is set to false it instantly loads the ContentView with no animated transition.

struct MyApp: App {
@State private var isLoading = true

```
var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup {
        ZStack {
            if isLoading {
                LoadingView()
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0), value: isLoading)
            } else {
                ContentView()
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 2.5), value: isLoading)

            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            startApp()
        }
    }
}

private func startApp() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
        isLoading = false
    }
}
```

}

Have tried a few different approaches though this code seems like the most plausible working solution.

Comment: Did you tried to put the isLoading=false in a WithAnimation block to tell SwiftUI you want to animate the change ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider replacing

```
.transition(.opacity)
.animation(.easeIn(duration: 2.5), value: isLoading)
```

by

```
.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`animation` is how the view `animate`, not how it `transit`, that's why it didn't work in the first place. There're many ways to fix your code, such as

1. Ask the father view to animate

```
ZStack {
    if isLoading {
        ProgressView()
            .transition(.opacity)
    } else {
        Text("ContentView")
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
}
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0), value: isLoading)
```

2. Stop transit the views

```
ProgressView()
    .opacity(isLoading ? 1 : 0)
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0), value: isLoading)
Text("ContentView")
    .opacity(isLoading ? 0 : 1)
    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0), value: isLoading)
```